# Is there ever a case when lookup is preferred to index-match?

Tags: excel, lookup, index-match

It seems that index-match can do almost everything that lookup can do. The only case I can think of for using lookup is when you want to find the last cell that meets a condition

e.g. last nonblank cell

```
=lookup(2, 1 / (lookup vector <> ""), lookup_vector)
```

Are there any other situations when lookup would be preferred?

Comment: Post your actual problem. In updated version of excel have lot of smart formula that can make your life easier.

Comment: `LOOKUP()` is nothing but a formula that will handle CSE natively. In that regard you might as well use `{=INDEX(lookup_vector,MATCH(2,1/(lookup_vector<>"")))}`. Not sure which would perform better in this particular case, but usually `VLOOKUP()` and `HLOOKUP()` are slower than a combination of `INDEX()`+`MATCH()`. We can now however use `XLOOKUP()` which (if I remember correctly) should be faster (and better).

Comment: Info about the various lookup functions (from the source): [LOOKUP Function](https://support.microsoft.com/office/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb). It says `LOOKUP` should not be used with arrays of cells.  Also here is [an article about performance](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/excel-performance-improvements-now-take-seconds-running-lookup/ba-p/254199) of various lookup function. ......These and lots more info about performance/usage of lookups is just a Google search away. (This isn't really a coding question; see "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve].)

Comment: For pre-`LET` versions of Excel, the potential gain in formula abbreviation is one small advantage `LOOKUP` holds over `INDEX`/`MATCH`. For example, `=LOOKUP("Ω",A:A)` and `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("Ω",A:A))` are equivalent, both returning the last text entry in column A. Here the visual difference is negligible, but replace the range `A:A` with some large construction which returns an array and the lack of repetition in the `LOOKUP` version makes it considerably more concise.

Comment: Which lookup? Hlookup(), vlookup(), lookup() or Xlookup()? Which are you testing?